# Hibernate Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails in OneToMany

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 classes: User, UserFormGroup and FormGroup. UserFormGroup has a ManyToOne reference on User and FormGroup. When I try to delete a FormGroup, I get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`form`.`user_form_group`, CONSTRAINT `FK_4on68h439dd6w05ikvl7vvvo5` FOREIGN KEY (`form_group_id`) REFERENCES `form_group` (`id`))
```

`
On FormGroup I have the following attribute:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=UserFormGroup.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "formGroup", orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<UserFormGroup> userFormGroups = new HashSet<>();
```

On UserFormGroup I have the following attribute:

```
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
private FormGroup formGroup;
```

Shouldn't orphan_removal=true remove UserFormGroup when the FormGroup is removed?
Could it come from the other relation between UserFormGroup and User? I can add this code if needed.

---

**EDIT**

Here is how I remove the FormGroup:

```
FormGroup group = groupRepository.findByIdAndMember(groupId, user);

if(group == null){
    return  new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
}

try {
    groupRepository.delete(group);
} catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
}
```

---

**SOLUTION**

I'm not sure what did the trick, but I think that I had to set the cascade to `CascadeType.REMOVE` on every table that was referencing UserFormGroup instead of `CascadeType.ALL` because `CascadeType.ALL` includes `CascadeType.PERSIST`.

Comment: add the removal method

Comment: I just added it. I use a DAO which extends CrudRepository with Spring Data.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I would say you need to define the a join column on the FormGroup dependency.

Without that, hibernate will try look for `formgroup_id` and on you database that column name is: `form_group_id`.

So having that said try to:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "form_group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private FormGroup formGroup;
```

**Edit**

On top of that, you would need to iterate through the `userFormGroups` and set to null the reference to the FormGroup for each of the entries:

```
for(UserFormGroup ufg: group.getUserFormGroups()){
      ufg.setFormGroup(null);
 }
 groupRepository.delete(group);
```

Comment: I want to delete the UserFormGroups when the group is deleted, should I use `userFormGroupRepository.delete(ufg);` in the for?

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work because there will still be references to those entities in the session. I would simply set to null each of the references to formgroup

Comment: I solved it and added the "solution" to my question. Thank you for the help!